# Swift UIView frame not properly updating within animateWithDuration

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, nslayoutconstraint, animatewithduration

I'm attempting to update a `UIView`'s position using `animateWithDuration`. When the animation starts occurring, the `UIView` begins updating, but then the completion makes it jump to the correct position. This is telling me that the setting of the `UIView`'s frame is not getting set correctly, but I'm not seeing why. Here is the code:

```
func showInfoView() {

    infoView.hidden = false
    let newPosition = self.view.frame.height - (self.infoView.frame.height + 260)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
        // Set the view to have the new y position
        self.infoView.frame.origin.y = newPosition
        }, completion: { finished in

            // Remove previous constraint
            if (self.hintConstraint != nil) {
                self.view.removeConstraint(self.hintConstraint)
            }

            // Create the new constraint
            self.hintConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.infoView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: newPosition)
            self.view.addConstraint(self.hintConstraint)
    })
}
```

Could anyone help me understand why the y position is not getting set properly within the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to animate with constraints, you should instead change the constraint and then call `layoutIfNeeded` in the animation block, on the parent view.

1) Set new constraint outside of the animation block

2) Within animation block, call `layoutIfNeeded` on parent view.

```
func showInfoView() {

    infoView.hidden = false
    let newPosition = self.view.frame.height - (self.infoView.frame.height + 260)
    self.hintConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.infoView, attribute: .Top, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Top, multiplier: 1, constant: newPosition)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, animations: {
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know you had to set the constraint outside of the animation block.